# textview superscript doesn't appear correctly

Tags: android, html, android-layout, textview, superscript

In my code I want set percent as a superscript of textview and I am using this code

```
 viewHolder.percent.setText(Html.fromHtml("-" + discount.getPercent() + "<sup>%</sup>"));
```

And when I run I have this result why?

There is no and padding or margin in my code.

[image]

Comment: Could you put your xml, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 viewHolder.percent.setText(Html.fromHtml("-" + discount.getPercent() + "<sup><small>%</small></sup>"));
```